VS Code ignores the installation of pandastable
I am trying to use pandastable, but although I already installed it with powershell it throws an error.
I already installed it with pip install pandastable in the powershell as an admin without any errors.
Still VS Code gives me:
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'pandastable'
  File "C:\DEV\the table scripts\the_app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandastable import Table
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandastable'

when I am trying to use it.
I already confirmed that I am using the correct python interpreter (python), I also confirmed that everything installed correctly as I tried to install it again, which said that every requrement is statisfied.

you may have common problem which you can see in many question - you may have installed two Pythons, and you install module for one Python but VS runs code with other Python. But Pythons don't share modules. In code run print( sys.executable ) to get /full/path/to/python and use it to install modules for correct Python - /full/path/to/python -m pip install ...
